# configuration file inb mongoDB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mongodb, morphia

i have problem

I'm using jelastic  to host java and mongoDB app.  And I have problem for the connection between my app and their mongoDB provide by Jelasctic.

Their config file look like this :

---

public class MongoManager {

```
static String host, dbname, user, password;

public void addData(int repeats) {
    try {
        DBCollection dbc = null;

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/mydb.cfg"));

        host = prop.getProperty("host").toString();
        dbname = prop.getProperty("dbname").toString();
        user = prop.getProperty("user").toString();
        password = prop.getProperty("password").toString();

        System.out.println("host: " + host + "\ndbname: " + dbname + "\nuser: " + user + "\npassword: " + password);

        Mongo m = new Mongo(host, 27017);
        DB db = m.getDB(dbname);

        if (db.authenticate(user, password.toCharArray())) {
            System.out.println("Connected!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Connection failed");
        }

        try {
            db.getCollection("mycollection");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            db.createCollection("mycollection", null);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Repeats: " + repeats);
            for (int i = 1; i <= repeats; i++) {
                BasicDBObject data = new BasicDBObject("data", new Date());
                db.getCollection("mycollection").save(data);
                System.out.println("INFO: row added " + data);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}
```

and mine

---

public class MongodbUtil {

```
private static Mongo mongo = null;
private static Morphia morphia = null;
private static Datastore ds = null;
private MongodbUtil() {};

public static synchronized DB getDB(String str) throws Exception {
    if(mongo == null) {
        mongo = new Mongo();
    }
    return mongo.getDB(str);
}
public static synchronized Mongo getMongo() throws Exception {
    if(mongo == null) {
        mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
    }
    return mongo;
}
public static synchronized Morphia getMorphia() throws Exception {
    if(morphia == null) {
        mongo = getMongo();
        morphia = new Morphia();
        morphia.mapPackage("com.sogeti.simulator.entity");
    }

    return morphia;
}
public static synchronized Datastore getDataStore(){
    if(ds == null){
        try {
            morphia = getMorphia();
            ds = morphia.createDatastore(mongo, "Simulator");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return ds;
}
```

IS that same file or not ?
How can i put in my config file properties like host ? password ? and others ?!

My MongoDB.cfg.xml looks like this  but i think this is bad because i don't use SPRING OR MAVEN :
i don'T see any example of a simple MongoDB.cfg.xml in the web.

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd;">

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.morphia.Morphia</groupId>
    <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
    <version>0.99</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mongodb.Mongo</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that similar problem was asked at Jelastic community [here](http://community.jelastic.com/index.php/topic/696-connect-java-application-to-mongodb).
The problem is resolved for that user, please pay your attention to the suggestions stated at that thread.